# Different sign in solution on probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is the problem 1.2.2 of Karlin's book *Introduction to stochastic modeling*:

> Let $N$ cards carry distinct numbers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$. If two cards are drawn at random without replacement show that the correlation coefficient $\rho$ between the numbers appearing in the two cards is $-1/(N-1)$

What I did was define 2 random variable: $C_1$ and $C_2$ that represent the different number $x_i$ on card one and card two respectively. After I define other two random variable derived from the others two that are the indicator functions ${\bf 1}_{C_1=x_i}$ and ${\bf 1}_{C_2=x_i}$.

Then I started evaluating the expected values $${\rm E}[{\bf 1}_{C_1=x_i}]=\Pr[C_1=x_i]=\frac1N\\ {\rm E}[{\bf 1}_{C_2=x_i}]=\Pr[C_2=x_i]=\Pr[C_2=x_i\mid C_1\ne x_i]\Pr[C_1\ne x_i]=\frac1N\quad \text{and}\\
{\rm E}[{\bf 1}_{C_1=x_i}{\bf 1}_{C_2=x_j}]=\Pr[C_1=x_i \cap C_2=x_j]=\frac{1}{N(N-1)}$$

And cause ${\rm Cov}[XY]={\rm E}[XY]-{\rm E}[X]{\rm E}[Y]$, ${\rm Var}[X]={\rm E}[X^2]-({\rm E}[X])^2$ and $\rho={\rm Cov}[XY]/({\rm Var}[X]^{1/2}{\rm Var}[Y]^{1/2})$ the answer that I get is $\rho=1/(N-1)$ what is different that the expected in the sign.

Can someone enlighten me please? I check the operations but they seems fine so Im unsure if my problem comes from a mistake in the formulation or the sign minus is a typo (what I think is not the case). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess with indicators.  Just calculate.
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(C_1) & = \dfrac{\sum_{i} x_i}N
\\[1ex] \mathsf E(C_1^2) & = \dfrac{\sum_{i} x_i^2}N
\\[1ex] \mathsf E(C_1C_2) & = \dfrac{\sum_{i}\sum_{j}x_ix_j - \sum_i x_i^2}{N(N-1)}
\\[3ex]
\mathsf{Corr}(C_1, C_2) & =\dfrac{\mathsf E(C_1C_2)-\mathsf E(C_1)\mathsf E(C_2)}{\sqrt{\mathsf E(C_1^2)-\mathsf E(C_1)^2}\sqrt{\mathsf E(C_2^2)-\mathsf E(C_2)^2}}
\\[2ex] & = \dfrac{\dfrac{\sum_{i}\sum_{j}x_ix_j - \sum_i x_i^2}{N(N-1)}-\dfrac{\sum_{i}\sum_{j} x_i x_j}{N^2}}{\dfrac{\sum_{i} x_i^2}N-\dfrac{\sum_{i}\sum_{j} x_i x_j}{N^2}}
\\[3ex]\therefore
\mathsf{Corr}(C_1, C_2)  & = \dfrac{\dfrac{s - t}{N(N-1)}-\dfrac{s}{N^2}}{\dfrac{t}N-\dfrac{s}{N^2}} & {s \mathop{:=} \sum_i\sum_j x_i x_j \,,\, t\mathop{:=} \sum_i x_i^2}
\end{align}$$

Now simplify so that the $s$ and $t$ cancel from the expression.